# R exclude list of dates not working

Tags: r, date

I have a situation where I am trying to exclude a list of dates ('2018-06-03','2018-06-04' for instance) using the %in% and ! operator but I have had no success. The code I am using:

Sample Data

```html
DATE         ORDER    SALES
2018-06-01  253626    200
2018-06-02  253621    300
2018-06-02  253621    100   
2018-06-03  253636    200
2018-06-03  253621    500 
2018-06-04  253621    500
2018-06-05  253621    500
```

```
var <- data %>% select(order,date,sales) %>% 
mutate(weekday = wday(date, label=TRUE)) %>% 
filter(!wday(date) %in% c(1, 7) & !(date %in% as.Date(c('2018-06-03','2018-06-04'))) %>%
 group_by(day=floor_date(date,"day")) %>% 
summarise(sales=sum(sales))
```

Expected output

```html
dates           sales 
2018-06-01      500
2018-06-02      400
2018-06-05      500
```

Any help ? Tks

Comment: In the first row of the output `sales` should be `200`. And the code works if you capitalize the column names in the pipe, like they are in the dataset example. I am voting to close as a simple typo.

Comment: also expected output should not have 2018-06-02 because `wday` is 7

Comment: @TCZhang Right, I missed that. Just remove `label = TRUE` from `mutate(weekday = wday(DATE))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the column `DATE` holds values which are dates? Or are they strings?

I tested the code below and it works. In the 1st case, `DATE` is a string whereas in `df2`, `DATE_D` is a date. In both cases, the records for 3rd and 4th June are removed.

```
df <- read.table(text = "
DATE         ORDER    SALES
2018-06-01  253626    200
2018-06-02  253621    300
2018-06-02  253621    100   
2018-06-03  253636    200
2018-06-03  253621    500 
2018-06-04  253621    500
2018-06-05  253621    500
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>%
  filter(!(DATE %in% c("2018-06-03", "2018-06-04")))

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(DATE_D = as.Date(DATE))

df2 %>%
  filter(!(DATE_D %in% as.Date(c("2018-06-03", "2018-06-04"))))
```

Comment: Hello rad ! The piece of code that missing was "mutate(DATE_D = as.Date(DATE))" . I have added this to the chain and the result was just what I expected. Still not sure why I had to use as.Date twice but it worked anyway. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
df<-data.frame(date=as.Date(c("2018/06/01","2018/06/01","2018/07/01"),),order=sample(21111:2220,3),sales=sample(100:300,3))

> df
        date order sales
1 2018-06-01  6001   185
2 2018-06-01  7494   229
3 2018-07-01 19223   169
#sample df
dates_exclude<-as.Date("2018/06/01") #dates you want to exlude

df[df$date!=dates_exclude,] #df exluding dates
df[!df$date %in% dates_exclude,] #df excluding dates using %in%

df[df$date!=dates_exclude,]
        date order sales
3 2018-07-01 19223   169
```